# Problema con DomPdf: Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `/tmp/ca_dompdf_img_3foHk2'

Tags: dompdf, imagemagick

Tengo un script en php, basado en dompdf, que me convierte el html en pdf. En el antiguo servidor todo iba bien, después que cambiaron en servidor hay un problema con las imágenes. Me sale este error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException:
>   NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `/temp/ca_dompdf_img_3foHk2' @
>   error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544 in
>   /var/www/vhosts/misitio.it/httpdocs/ldv/dompdf/lib/Cpdf.php:4862 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   /var/www/vhosts/misitio.it/httpdocs/ldv/dompdf/lib/Cpdf.php(4862):
>   Imagick->__construct('/var/www/vhosts...') #1
>   /var/www/vhosts/misitio.it/httpdocs/ldv/dompdf/lib/Cpdf.php(4984):
>   Cpdf->addImagePngAlpha('/var/www/vhosts...', 499.0142519685,
>   739.6242519685, 75, 75, 3) #2 /var/www/vhosts/misitio.it/httpdocs/ldv/dompdf/src/Adapter/CPDF.php(845):
>   Cpdf->addPngFromFile('/var/www/vhosts...', 499.0142519685,
>   739.6242519685, 75, 75) #3 /var/www/vhosts/misitio.it/httpdocs/ldv/dompdf/src/Renderer/Image.php(110):
>   Dompdf\Adapter\CPDF->image('/var/www/vhosts...', 499.0142519685,
>   27.265748031496, 75, 75, 'normal') #4 /var/www/vhosts/misitio.it/httpdocs/ldv/dompdf/src/Renderer.php(293):
>   Dompdf\Renderer\Image->render(Object(Dompdf\FrameDecorator\Image)) #5
>   /var/www/ in
>   /var/www/vhosts/misitio.it/httpdocs/ldv/dompdf/lib/Cpdf.php on line
>   4862

De lo que entiendo, me parece que el script guarde las imágenes creadad dinamicamente en una carpeta temporánea y luego no pueda acceder al formato de esas imágenes. Todas esas imáganes en la carpeta temporánea empiezan por ca_dompdf_img así que no encuentra el delegado de image magick para esas imágenes. He intentado cambiar carpeta temporánea, he puesto los permisos a 777 o 775, pero no cambia nada. ¿Qué puede ser?

Answer (score 0):

He resuelto. Era suficiente reiniciar el servidor.